# Single Site Collection growing above 200 GB limit

Tags: 2010, site-collection, content-database, limitations

What is the recommended approach when a single site collection (on a Content Database) is growing above the 200 GB limit?

All files are stored in the same site collection, within different sites and document libraries. Most of the contents are office files.

I want to keep the files indexed and searchable. And maintainable doing backup and restore.

Answer (score 2):

To manage site collection size growth, I would recommend to create an Archive site collection (with separate Content database). Use the primary site collection to store only "actual" data.

Steps:

- Create an additional site collection that contains archive data
- Implement archiving process for moving expired data into archive

### About archiving process

Information management policies is a no-code solution for implementing archiving process in SharePoint. Setup a Retention policy with action `Transfer to another location`

### References

[Create and apply information management policies](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-HA101631505.aspx)

[Managing Information Management Policy in SharePoint Server 2010 (ECM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499244.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You ought to break your content up into new site collections and content databases. This can be accomplished by creating new empty site collections within new empty content DBs and migrating content (webs) to your new site collections. You may also consider creating a new (or modifying existing) managed paths in order to maintain legacy links to your content. It's a big job, but definitely doable.